# why python file-write doesn't implicitly call class __str__?

Tags: python, string

Why doesn't Python's file write automatically call `__str__`?

```
$ cat person.py
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 22
    def __str__(self):
        return "my age is {}".format(self.age)
```

When I try to print it, everything goes fine, but writing `Person` to file fails:

```
>>> from person import Person
>>> dan = Person()
>>> print(dan)
my age is 22
>>> fl = open("dan.txt","wt")
>>> fl.write(dan)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Person
```

Comment: Python is *strongly* typed, there aren't implicit conversions (`"hello " + dan` wouldn't work either). Be explicit, use `fl.write(str(dan))`. This is specifically mentioned in e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files.

Comment: Because when writing a data structure to a file, you don’t always want it in the human-readable form.

Comment: `__str__` is **not** a "cast to `str`" method that is called whenever a `str` is required...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simply not how the API is designed.

From [the definition of `object.__str__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__):

> Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object.

Beyond those explicitly listed instances, there's no reason to expect that implicit conversion will occur.

And from [the definition of `io.TextIOBase.write(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write):

> Write the string s to the stream and return the number of characters written.

So it's explicitly expecting a string, which is confirmed by the error message.

The simplest solution is to perform the conversion by using the `str()` function before passing it `write()` as an argument:

```py
fl.write(str(dan))
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to print it, everything goes fine, but writing `Person` to file fails

Why not use `print` then?

```
print(dan, file=fl)
```

That will behave exactly like the print you are expecting (including a trailing newline), but write to a file instead of stdout.